# Return to Modal View Controller after a phone call comes in?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, background

I have a situation where I am showing a modal view controller and, if a call comes in, the view controller is gone when the app resumes.  Is there a way to make is so the modal view controller is still there when the user returns to the app?

Thank you.

Comment: I have the same issue. My question is, why is this happening?  Is this expected behavior, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Use these delegates and check to see if that Modal is visible, if it is, then when the app re-enters foreground, present the modal again.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application 
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```